# Save order of SELECT result in complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I need to sort `selected_booking` by `cost` first and then assign the index `i` to every row. My variant doesn't work properly (outer SELECT breaks the order):

`SELECT (@i:=@i + 1) AS i, selected_booking.*
 FROM (SELECT * FROM booking ORDER BY cost DESC) AS selected_booking;`

Is there any way to save the order of inner selection when doing outer one?

Comment: I'm not aware of any MySQL syntax that provides "preserve the order of rows from a rowsource". I don't think there is any. If you need rows in a particular sequence, use an `ORDER BY` clause. It seems like you are asking if there's any shorthand for `ORDER BY selected_booking.cost DESC` on the outer query. And nope, that's as short as it gets (The only way to make that shorter would be to use a *shorter* alias for your inline view/derived table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is there any way to save the order of inner selection when doing outer selection?

A: Absent an ORDER BY clause on the outer query, MySQL is free to return the rows in any order it chooses.

If you want rows from the inline view (derived table) returned in a specific order, you need to specify that in the outer query... you'd need to add an `ORDER BY` clause on the outer query.

---

NOTE: The behavior of user-defined variables as in your query is not *guaranteed*, the MySQL Reference Manual warns of this. But in spite of that warning, we do observe repeatable behavior in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5.

It's not at all clear why you need an inline view (aka a *derived table*, in the MySQL venacular) in the example you give.

It seems like this query would return the result you seem to want:

```
 SET @i = 0 ;
 SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS i 
      , b.*
   FROM booking b
  ORDER BY b.cost DESC ;
```

Alternatively, you could do this in a single statement, and initialize `@i` within the query, rather than a separate SET statement.

```
 SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS i 
      , b.*
   FROM booking b
   JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) i
  ORDER BY b.cost DESC
```

(This initialization works, again, because of the way the MySQL processes inline views, the inline view query is run BEFORE the outer query. This isn't guaranteed behavior, and may change in a future release (it may have already changed in 5.6)

NOTE: For improved performance of this query, if a suitable index is available with `cost` as the leading column, e.g.

```
... ON booking (cost)
```

that may allow MySQL to use that index to return rows in order and avoid a "Using filesort" operation.

Comment: Actually a want to get bookings ordered by cost, and than assign the index not breaking the order. I mean the result should be ordered by cost DESC and by index ASC simultaneously. I try to use outer SELECT here only to assign the. Maybe i can do it some other way, without outer SELECT?

Comment: Just do the assignment to the derived column `i` in the same query that has the `ORDER BY`. MySQL will "order" the rows *before* it evaluates the expressions in the SELECT list. (This isn't guaranteed behavior, but it's the behavior we observe in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5)